# How to remove the icon displayed by Particle System in Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, icons, particle-system

I have a particle system in my Unity Android project and it is working very well. I wanted it to play only once so disabled looping.
Now the problem is once the particle system has finished playing, a weird icon as below appears on the screen. 
[Icon Displayed by Particle System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKC6U.png)
That does not look good. I altered my coding so that as soon as the animation is played, the particle system is taken off screen. But still that icon is displayed even though for a very very short period of time.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is scene view gizmo for particle system. It will not appear in the game view.

If you still don't want it. Disable as the screenshot by clicking on the icon in the Gizmos dropdown menu.

[image]